# Type of value in Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using C# to read an excel sheet and use the following code to read the values:

```
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
object value = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).get_Value(Type.Missing);
```

In case an integer number appears there (for example 2), then it shows me as float: 2.0

How could I know if it's an float or integer there?

More than that, how could I know if a string is stored in the cell, or integer or float?

Thanks
Moti

Comment: You can convert the entry to int, then compare to its origional value against your conversion. And the same with float

Comment: From my own little experience with Excel, it "calculates" the type per column. If the whole column is just integers, each cell in the column will be integer. If one is floating point number and the rest are integers, the whole column will become `float` etc. Can't find any official documentation for this, hence only comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure is Excel makes difference between integers and floats -- you can enter 1 to cell and then move decimal point making it look like 1.00.
To figure out whether it is integer or not you may try the following:

```
var r;
if (Int32.TryParse(value, out r))
{
    // r now stores int value
}
```

`float.TryParse()` is also there :)

Comment: But what would happen if the value is null?